# jquery check and uncheck all with action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unchecked

I have more checkbox input that call function "boxclick" when the user click on this:

```
<input id="1box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]" onclick="boxclick(this,'1')">
<input id="2box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]" onclick="boxclick(this,'2')">
<input id="3box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]" onclick="boxclick(this,'3')">
<input id="4box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]" onclick="boxclick(this,'4')">
```

For check/uncheck all i use simple jquery script:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', this.checked);" checked="checked">
```

My problem is when i check/uncheck all the function "boxclick" not run.

```
  // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
    } else {
      hide(category);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you tell me breif...?i think you want to check all is one checkbox is checked...??right.?

Comment: Can you show us what the function `boxclick` looks like?

Comment: i have update my question with the boxclick code

Answer (score 2):

Setting attribute of checkboxes to checked does not automatically fake a click event for you! Because you put those boxclick function calls within some "onclick" handlers, you must trigger a fake click event in order for your javascript to think that it **clicked** all the boxes. To trigger fake click event use $('#whatever').trigger('click'), for instance:

```
$('input[name*=\'selected\']').trigger('click');
```

If you want check/uncheck all functionality, you must say "ok, master checkbox, please listen for whenever I am checked or unchecked. When that happens, please set checked attribute of my slave boxes (your other boxes on the page) to *match* the *master's* current checked attribute." Like this:

```
function checkAllorUncheckAll(event){

    var chiefCheckbx = event.currentTarget;
    var myBoxes = $('input[name*=\'selected\']'); 

    myBoxes.prop( "checked", $(chiefCheckbx).prop("checked") ).trigger('click');

}

$('#masterCheckBox').on('change',checkAllorUncheckAll);
```

Comment: Thk for the answer, by default my checkboxes are all checked, how resolve?

Comment: You want to uncheck/check all with that one master checkbox I see, so please see my reworked answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do:

***HTML***

```
<input id="1box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
<input id="2box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
<input id="3box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
<input id="4box" type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
```

***jQuery***

If you want to check/uncheck all `checkbox`:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox][name^=selected]');
checkboxes.on('click', function() {
   checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

If you want to make select any one at a time:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox][name^=selected]');
checkboxes.on('click', function() {
   checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
   this.checked = !this.checked;
});​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7SM7V/)***

Comment: That would check all checkboxes whenever you clicked on any single one of them, and would never allow you to uncheck them, neither of which seems to be the functionality they're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> `$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked',
>   this.checked).trigger('click');`

should do the trick here

Comment: if the OP's boxclick function already individually checks each box, then attr('checked', this.checked) chain should not be there. The OP did not post that boxclick function code, so we cannot be sure at the moment, though if OP wants, doing .attr('checked', this.checked) is definitely valid if the OP's boxClick functions do not check/ uncheck/toggle the individual boxes already (though if it is a toggle, OP will ned to watch out - boxClick code may conflict with what OP is really trying to do then!

Comment: @sajawikio He said that function boxClick was not getting called up on setting attr to checked.It wont be because it was never actually clicked.So I told him to trigger click event after setting the attr to checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/H37cb/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" /></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function(){
var status = $(this).is(':checked');
$('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', status);
});

});
</script>




<div id="wrapper">
 <li style="margin-top: 20px">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" /> <label for='all'>All</label>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title_1" /> <label for="title_1"><strong>Title 01</strong></label>
    <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_1" value="1" /> <label for="box_1">Sub Title 01</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_2" value="2" /> <label for="box_2">Sub Title 02</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_3" value="3" /> <label for="box_3">Sub Title 03</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_4" value="4" /> <label for="box_4">Sub Title 04</label></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title_2" /> <label for="title_2"><strong>Title 02</strong></label>
    <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_5" value="5" /> <label for="box_5">Sub Title 05</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_6" value="6" /> <label for="box_6">Sub Title 06</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_7" value="7" /> <label for="box_7">Sub Title 07</label></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer may be more beneficial to the OP and others who see it later if you explain _how_ it fixes the problem. We generally prefer detailed explanations over code blocks even when the code is accurate.